# Using TFS 2017 To Build WCF Service Doesnt Output .SVC Files

Tags: wcf, tfs, svc

I'm able to get my project to build just fine using TFS 2017 Visual Studio Build step.  However in the output directory there are no .SVC files.  Am i missing a step that produces these?

I have searched for this online and i still haven't found a solution that makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Build a WCF in VS locally will also not copy the `.svc` file by default. Right click  the file and select properties, the default value of **Build Action** is `content` and **Copy to Output Directory** is `Do not Copy`.

If you really want to copy this file, you could add a task in your `.csproj` file to achieve it. A sample for your reference:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <SolutionDir>$([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($(MSBuildProjectDirectory)))</SolutionDir>
    </PropertyGroup>



    <PropertyGroup>
      <CopyFileOutput>$(SolutionDir)\WebUI.UnitTest\bin\Debug\WebUI.UnitTest.dll;$(SolutionDir)\Core.UnitTest\bin\Debug\Core.UnitTest.dll</CopyFileOutput>
    </PropertyGroup>



    <Copy
      SourceFiles="$(CopyFileOutput)"
      DestinationFolder="$(SolutionDir)\WebUI\bin"
     />

  </Target>
```